# Using views preprocesses to add css and js to a view

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to add css and js to a view via a preprocess in my template.php.

I've created themename_preprocess_views_view_my_view_name($vars) and added in my drupal_add_js/css but its not working. The view loads fine but the added css and js are not outputted. My drupal_add_js syntax is correct because I've tested it in a hook_nodeapi in a custom module. The documentation is really unclear as to how to use the function with views.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had something similar to me happen with styles.  I would add stylesheets via the drupal_add_css method in a preprocess function but they would not appear on the page.  What I assumed is that the $styles variable was already populated.  I resolved by setting $vars['styles'] to drupal_get_css.  Example:

```
drupal_add_css(path_to_theme() . '/css/foo.css','theme','all');
$vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css();
```

You can try to see if the same thing is happening with your scripts.  Example:

```
drupal_add_js(path_to_theme() . '/js/foo.js');
$vars['scripts'] = drupal_get_js();
```

Answer (score 0):

are you sure that your preprocess is being picked up? the naming can be a little funky sometimes. I recommend using the devel themer module from the devel module that allows you to view which theme functions and overrides are being used.